# Avoid gRPC message exceeds maximum size

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-python, chunking

I'm using gRPC to send messages from Java to a Python service. Recently I started getting larger messages that sometimes exceed the maximum message size for gRPC. Increasing that size is not possible for me due to lack of resources and timeouts, so I had to implement a chunking mechanism in order to split the large messages.

In Java, I check the message size using getSerializedSize() and if it exceeds the maximum size, I do the chunking. However, I noticed that the value I'm getting from getSerializedSize() is different and much smaller than the one shown in the error "gRPC message exceeds maximum size" which means that I still send messages that exhaust the resources.

For example, how is it possible that getSerializedSize() returns 75274 and the error shows a size of 179651? Both are supposed to show the size in bytes. I also tried getting the size using the length of the byte array, but it is identical to getSerializedSize().

How can I know the actual size gRPC will get before sending the message so I can apply the chunking when I should?